# Oracle 11g and Database Connection

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I need to have access to a SQL worksheet in 11g for my coursework. In university I have access to a Oracle server but I wish to do it on my laptop and there is no way for me to connect to that Oracle sever. How can I get a database connection to allow me to access the SQL worksheet without actually connecting to a real database. Virtual database? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download [Oracle XE (Express Edition)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html) on your machine. Theoretically it should not be *that much* heavy. I don't find a XE for 11g, but the differences should not be visible for a coursework.

Comment: Thanks :). I've downloaded it... I can't seem to get 11g to get a successful connection in 'Edit Database Connection' pop up window. I've created a user with a password in XE. What connection type would it need to be in 11g? (Sorry, I'm not a server expert. they've put me into the deepend)

Comment: to be honest, I'm not an Oracle server expert as well (it is really boring and hard at the same time :D ). So I don't know about the connection type (haven't used 11g)

Comment: I managed to connect to the server. I ran 'lsnrctl status' in command prompt then I looked at the listeners. and instead of using my localhost and that given port. I used My Laptop's name and port :)